# How to convert set of tags to belongness tuple ("multi-hot" encoding) in Python easy?

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I have a set of tags `tags` and an ordered list of all possible tags `taglist`. Now I want to convert set of tags into "multi-hot" encoding, i.e. get a list or tuple with the same length as `taglist` and which has ones in places, where belonging tag resides and zeros in other placess.

Currently I do traightforward:

```
        multihot = []
        for i in range(len(taglist)):
            tag = taglist[i]
            if tag in tags:
                multihot.append(1)
            else:
                multihot.append(0)
```

Is it possible to write one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach it with list comprehension, adding condition whether tag is in tags, if yes, insert 1 else 0.

```
multihot = [1 if tag in tags else 0 for tag in taglist]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
multihot = [(tag in tags) for tag in tag_list]
```

multihot now contains entries of True or False. In Python, True behaves exactly the same as 1, and False as 0; so this is equivalent to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are doing multi-label encoding. `sklearn` can do that for you:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer